# update mysql table each row in with where condition one query

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Hi I'm trying to update each row-column in a mysql table with where condition

```
update city set (ID='1001' where ID='1') and (ID='1002' where ID='2');
```

but this seems not working Can anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
update city 
set ID = case ID
  when '1' then '1001' 
  when '2' then '1002' 
end
where ID IN ('1', '2');
```

or simpler:

```
update city 
set ID = ID + 1000
where ID IN ('1', '2');
```

Comment: I already tried this query but it gives the error "Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '1001' for key 'city.PRIMARY'"

Comment: @developerKris this means that there is already in the table another row with ID=1001. I assume that ID is the primary key of the table so there can't be any duplicates. Did you check the table?

Comment: Yes, I didn't check it that I have a duplicate of it. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: what if I have to update more columns instead of ID? any suggestions?

Comment: @developerKris just use `,` and add the columns after the 1st column  and before the WHERE clause:  update city 
set ID = ID + 1000, anothercolumn=0, andanothercolumn=2
where ID IN ('1', '2');

Comment: is there any example that you can provide? Thanks!

Comment: @developerKris see my previous comment for an example. All the columns that you want to update must be separated by commas.

Answer (score 1):

Like the comment above, I would do this as two separate queries:

```
update city set ID='1001' where ID='1'; 

update city set ID='1002' where ID='2';
```

There is an advantage in keeping code as simple as possible. It stays easier to modify in the future.

But if you must do it in one statement:

```
update city
set ID = CASE ID WHEN '1' THEN '1001' WHEN '2' THEN '1002' END
where ID IN ('1', '2');
```